# "in all" restriction for Grails/Hibernate Criteria Query

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria, grails-2.0

I need an way to do "in all" criteria queries in Grails/Hibernate.  The standard "in" restriction is what I would call an "in any" restriction.

By way of example...

**The Preamble**

Take a domain class "Knights" that has a many-to-many association with another domain class "Perils".  The classes are simple...

```
class Knight {
  String name
  static hasMany = [perils:Peril]   
}

class Peril {
  String name
  static hasMany = [knights:Knight]
  static belongsTo = Knight
}
```

The table content looks like this...

```
    Knights
    1 Arthur, King of the Britains (Not technically a knight. I know, I know.)
    2 Sir Bedevere the Wise
    3 Sir Lancelot the Brave
    4 Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-As-Sir-Lancelot
    5 Sir Galahad the Pure

    Perils
    1 Black Knight
    2 Knights who say Ni
    3 Three-Headed Giant
    4 Swamp Castle
    5 Castle Anthrax
    6 Rabbit of Caerbannog

    Knights_Perils
    1, 1       // arthur fights the black knight
    1, 2       // arthur fights the knights who say ni
    2, 2       // bedevere fights the knights who say ni
    4, 3       // Robin runs-away from Three-Headed Giant
    3, 4       // Lancelot Assaults Swamp Castle
    5, 5       // Galahad visits Castle Anthrax
    3, 5       // Lancelot "rescues" Galahad from Castle Anthrax
    1, 6       // All Knights fight the Killer Bunny
    2, 6       // ...
    3, 6       // ...
    4, 6       // ...
    5, 6       // ...
```

I present a form that offers checkboxes to search on the association...

```
    Choose Perils and Search for Knights...
     [ ] Black Knight (id 1)
     [ ] Knights who say Ni (id 2)
     [ ] Three-Headed Giant (id 3)
     [x] Swamp Castle (id 4)
     [x] Castle Anthrax (id 5)
     [x] Killer Bunny (id 6)

     [search]
```

And I query like this:

```
def query = Knights.createQuery()
query.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset) {
  if(params.perils) perils { 'in' ('id', params.list('perils')*.toLong()) }
}
```

That yields what I call "in any" results.  Knight's with an association "in any" of the the list of checked perils.  In the case of the 3 checked perils in the form above, all the knights...

```
    Arthur - fights bunny
    Bedevere - fights bunny
    Lancelot - swamp castle, castle anthrax, fights bunny
    Robin - fights bunny
    Galahad - castle anthrax, fights bunny
```

**The Question**

I'm looking for a Hibernate/Grails criteria restriction similar to "in" but that will query "in all".  In other words, Knight's with an association "in all" of the checked perils in the list.  With this restriction, and the same form input above, I would expect the results to be only

```
    Lancelot - swamp castle, castle anthrax, fights bunny
```

Is there an "in all" version of the Hibernate criteria "in" restriction?

Remember, I'm wanting to do this with CriteriaQuery (in either Hibernate or Grails dialect), not direct SQL or HQL.

Any pointers on how to tackle this?

Thank you!

- Gary

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Maybe there's a better option, because I don't know every aspect of SQL/HQL, but the following clause:

```
all the selected perils are in the knight's perils
```

can also be expressed like this

```
there is no peril in the selected perils that is not in the knight's perils
```

So, in HQL, you can express it like this:

```
select knight from Knight knight
where not exists (select peril.id from Peril peril 
                  where peril.id in :selectedPerilIds
                  and peril.id not in (select peril2.id from Peril peril2
                                       where peril2.knight.id = knight.id))
```